# Calling the same function after input text field touch

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll

I'm using an javaScript scroll framework - build an nice scrollbar to windows. I just add it to a div:

```
 this.displayDiv = function () {
        $("#myDiv").niceScroll();
    }

    <a href="#" onclick="manager.displayDiv();">
```

In my mobile device (HTML5 app) it's working good, When I call it from a `form window` with `input text` field it display it OK, but when I just touch an input text field (writing something or not) and getting the `focus effect`, after that trying to start it again the scroll doesn't work.
Cant figure it out...what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
function scrolling() {
    $("#myDiv").niceScroll();
}

<a href="#" id="myDiv" onclick="function scrolling()"> Click me to scroll. </a>
```

Comment: And what the different with my code??? it's working fine...the question was about the connection of text fields

Answer (score 0):

What is mobile device do you use? I tested on iOS 5, no issues found.

Try this example page:

http://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/test/mutation.html

If problem persists, please open an issue on github:

https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues

Comment: Can I just add the same div that the script add to my DIV that I want to scroll : `<div id="ascrail2000" style="width: 7px; z-index: 6000; position: absolute; top....` and set it somehow to scroll my specific DIV?